# Front-end Authorization is INSECURE, almost always. Don't you agree?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, authorization, firefox-addon, single-page-application

I’m in web dev since many years ago, but I still do not believe you can easily implement user authorization in front-end apps or browser extensions.

While front-end authentication can be achieved (cookies, jwt, etc.) and works fairly well, the same is not for authorization. The common example is when you want to restrict access to some content and/or functionalities to logged-in users only.

I am inspecting many browser extensions and web apps, and I usually find something like this pseudocode:

```
if (user.isLogged === true) {
    // code to show ui components and actions
} else {
    // code to show ui components and actions
}
```

which is **highly insecure**.

For instance, this is coming from an extension available on the chrome web store:

```
function initApp() {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in. var uid = user.uid; window.location.href = "app.html";
                const uid = user.uid;
                const name = user.displayName;
                getUserData(uid);

                // Plus a lot of other code to show/hide ui components and actions

            } else { }
            document
                .getElementById('quickstart-button')
                .disabled = false;
        });

    document
        .getElementById('quickstart-button')
        .addEventListener('click', startSignIn, false);
}
```

The only secure way is to actually load HTML and JS chunks dynamically only when and if the user is authorized to access that page/functionality, where the server decides which chunks serve to the current user based on his role, and then those chunks are injected at runtime. But this is, on one hand, failing with the spa architecture itself because it's very near to serving the app server-side (**it's never the client to decide what to show**). It also requires injecting HTML markup dynamically using JS which is **not ideal for security**. Plus, this is something **not trivial to implement**, so I guess **the majority of js apps out there are handling restricted content/areas using the paradigm shown above**, based on the current in-memory/store (or in cookie/storage) state of the current user, which is highly insecure and can be easily manipulated by the end-user. Especially in browser extensions where you are not even allowed to obfuscate the code.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** you are right, don't rely on front-end security. There is none. Grab the secret content from a backend and require authentication.

You mentioned SPAs so let's analyze the situation there.

Assume you have a React App with a main component looking similar to this:

```
function App() {

  const { loggedIn, isSpecialUser } = useContext(authContext);

  if (loggedIn)
     return <MainPage />;

  if (isSpecialUser)
     return <SuperSecretPage />;

  return <LoginPage />;
}
```

The `loggedIn` and `isSpecialUser` state is dynamically set after the user logged in (or relogin by cookies, jwt, whatever).
Therefore the restricted areas for MainPage and SuperSecretPage will only show after the user logged in.

*So what if the user looks at the source of the SuperSecretPage?*

He should see something like this:

```
function App() {

  const { token } = useContext(authContext);
  const { data } = useApi(getSuperSecretContent, token);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}
```

Even if the super secret content is static for all user, it should be fetched with a separate call that requires a token. Access rights must be checked by the backend. If you just write your content in there, it can be seen by *everyone*.

---

**Edit** Response to OP's comment. He wrote

> a malicious user has at least 2 options: 1) change the js content of the main App component, to let's say  return ; when the user is not logged in at all; 2) manually change the ajax callback to set his status to Superuser regardless of the actual response.

For both ways, the user would just break the clients rendering but not the security. In any case, the client must make an API-call to receive the secret content:

```
const { data } = useApi(getSuperSecretContent, token);
```

`useApi` is an abstract hook that uses some sort of API (e.g. REST-API) to fetch the content during runtime (ajax). The second parameter is a token. This token must be some sort of authentication token the servers sends the user after login. This token here is the **crucial** part (see OAuth, JWT). For each ajax call to get the super secret content, a valid token must be supplied. The backend then has to check if the token is valid. If and only if the token is valid, the backend returns the super secret content.

Pseudocode `useApi`:

```
function useApi(apiCall, token) {
  make ajax request {
    endpoint: apiCall,
    authorization header: token
  }
  if success:
     return data
  else if auth error:
     return error
}
```

Pseudocode backend:

```
get request to super secret content:
  if token is not valid:
     return auth error;
  else
     return super secret content
```

The user cannot trick the backend into sending him the super secret content by manipulating the frontend state.

---

**Edit 2** Response to OP's confusion about authentication and authorization.

You must use the token also for authorization. In case of a JWT for instance, the token itself can include infos about rights management, otherwise you could query access rights from a database for a given user.

This must happen during the request handling @backend side.

Pseudocode backend e.g.:

```
get request to super secret content:
  get access rights for token

  if access rights include super secret resources:
     return super secret content;
  else
     return auth error;
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. However a malicious user has at least 2 options: 1) change the js content of the main App component, to let's say  ```return <SuperSecretPage />;``` when the user is not logged in at all; 2) manually change the ajax callback to set his status to Superuser regardless of the actual response. This is not for basic users of course, but it's still perfectly possible since we are deciding what to show in the fronted...

Comment: @Mauro please see my edit. I think you misunderstood a crucial part. You must fetch secret content dynamically and provide a authorization token for each call. This token must not be craftable by the user (via digital signatures, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think here we are mixing again authentication and authorization. I understand we pass the token at every call because of course we are not maintaining any sessions on the server itself. However in your example{ data} contains the custom component, so we need 2 calls one to render the right component and one inside the component to fetch the content data.

Comment: @Mauro We don't mix authentication and authorization here. Your backend is responsible for both. At first your client authenticates and receives e.g. an authentication token. This token can include infos about rights management or the token is used to grab infos about authorization. If your client then sends a resource request, the backend must use the token to check if the token is allowed to access the requested resource. In case of a JWT, the payload can contain Infos about what resources can be accesed. If you do SSR instead of SPA, you can handle everything directly inside your backend.